# When the match time is called, does the current turn end immediately?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-competitive-rel, mtg-regular-rel

In the Magic Tournament Rules, [the End-of-Match procedure](https://blogs.magicjudges.org/rules/mtr2-5/) says:

> If the match time limit is reached before a winner is determined, the player whose turn it is finishes their turn and five additional turns are played in total.

In a Regular or Competitive REL tournament, does this mean the turn immediately ends (as though [Sundial of the Infinite](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSundial%20of%20the%20Infinite%5d) was activated), or does it mean the current player continues their turn through ordinary gameplay and draws it to a speedy conclusion so that the five extra turns can commence?

I've only been to a couple of pre-releases as far as tournament exposure goes, and I'm looking to better understand tournament procedure. I don't want to join a tournament and have an incorrect understanding of this situation cost me a game.

Comment: For what it's worth, this rule predates the card Sundial of the Infinite (and indeed its predecessor Time Stop) by at least a decade if not more.  At the time this rule was invented, there was no concept of what it would mean for the game state if a turn was ended except inasmuch as drawn to a natural conclusion (by stepping through all the steps/phases and saying "go").

Comment: @Ertai87 I suppose technically winning the game would be another way of ending the turn.

Answer (score 21):

The active player takes the rest of the turn as usual, then the five-turn count begins. This is based on my own experience, but it is likely that if they wanted to end the turn immediately they would have used a wording that matched the corresponding effect template and said "End the turn".

Overall, it would not really make sense to end that turn like that. It would effectively be introducing a somewhat complex effect into a running game from the outside with no respect for the stack, priority, or turn-based actions. It would create arguments about what the game state is and what spells/abilities/effects have already resolved. Plus it wouldn't do much for timeliness because it would effectively say "The active player immediately stops what they're doing and ends the turn, then both players return to playing at their own pace for another five turns". Finally, the active player already has the disadvantage of getting only two of the five turns; adding this further disadvantage to the same player could unreasonably swing the game.

As some comments have mentioned, the quoted section of the Magic Tournament Rules was added before the concept of "ending the turn" was ever created in the Comprehensive Rules. So, the intention at the time that the tournament rules were written could not have been to end the turn in that way.

Comment: Might be worth adding a ref to CR 716, *Ending the turn* as it is used on Sundial, as opposed to plain English tournament rules.

Comment: @Hackworth The thing is, MTR isn't beholden to Magic templating. So, sure, it's written in plain English, but that is the exact reason I thought it might possibly mean “the turn ends immediately”.

Comment: @doppelgreener Exactly, MTR wording is not bound by CR wording. So if the MTR meaning of *finish* was in effect the same as CR 716 *end*, the MTR would have to define what *finish* means in the same depth as the CR does for *end*, or make an explicit ref to the CR. The MTR can't just impose a Sundial effect on the active player and not explain what that entails, unless, of course, it was the normal English meaning of normally finishing the turn, all steps and phases intact.

Comment: I'm just pointing out, saying "it's plain English" doesn't make it as clear as you and others seem to think it might. I mean, I read it, I know it's plain English, I still did not known how to interpret it.

Comment: As for the English interpretation, there are still differences to point out. To me as a non-native, "finishing" something means to bring something to a *successful, goal-oriented* end, rather than *any* end. Everything that finishes ends, but not everything that ends finishes, if that makes sense. A finished turn means all steps and phases have been passed normally, while an ended turn can mean either finished or aborted as per CR 716.

Comment: [Google on end vs. finish](https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&ei=qlbcXJ6YGMzKgwe08aLYBw&q=difference+end+finish&oq=difference+end+finish&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i22i30.24094.26346..26586...0.0..0.105.1502.20j1......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j0j0i10j0i22i10i30.LFYDxm1-ZIM)

Comment: @Hackworth I am a native English speaker, and my understanding of what "finish" means matches yours.

Comment: There *is* a process for ending the turn at *most* points in the turn (any time you could play an instant), because there is a card that actually does that. Of course, it includes such fun side effects as "Exile everything on the stack, including this card, but it will continue to resolve."

Comment: @Kevin That rule post-dates this rule by at least a decade.  At the time this tournament rule was in place, those cards (and their associated rules) did not exist.  Although without context, it's hard to know that.

Comment: When explaining it to new players I use the shorthand that the current turn is Turn 0, and you have five full turns to finish the game otherwise it's a draw.