# What is the most life you can have at the end of your first turn with only three cards?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, puzzles

You start this game with 3 cards of your choice in hand.
Your opponent starts with 0 cards in their hand.
Both libraries do not contain any other useful cards.

What is the highest life total you can end your turn at?

Assume you start at 20 life points. Beyond that, the rules can follow any of the [official two-player formats by Wizard of the Coast](https://magic.wizards.com/en/game-info/gameplay/rules-and-formats/formats).

---

*Extra Challenge: If you want a personal challenge (although this is not what I am looking for in the answers to this question), try to find the 4-card infinite-life combo that made me restrict the puzzle to 3 cards only.*

Comment: Define "useful cards"... can you use cards in your library in some way as long as you aren't casting them or otherwise caring about what specific cards they are?

Comment: @GendoIkari If a specific card is needed for the solution to work, that card is not in either library. If *any* card would work, that's fine (such as if hand-size or discard is needed)

Comment: Would it be allowed to specify that the library contains all creature cards; if it doesn't matter what cards they are?

Comment: @Gendolkari Probably not. In that case creatures would be useful cards since they are vital to the solution.

Comment: @DavidCoffron When you say "end your turn", do you mean that the opponent has to be alive after whatever actions I take until the regular end of my turn, or can the combo immediately win the game as well?

Comment: There is a cheating answer which only uses two of my cards, but requires the top card of the opponent's library to be something specific.

Comment: It seems to me to depend on 2 things. What is the legality rules, and what is your starting life total? A few of my friends made a format where you start at 500+ life, or you could be at 40, or 20! Please specify.

Comment: Specifically, could you be playing commander

Comment: @CollinB Addressed

Comment: That hasn't really clarified anything. Commander is one of the listed formats, and it explicitly allows for 2 players. If you want to start at 20 life, just say that. Otherwise, you might as well just say that you start at 40 life and bump everyone's score up by 20.

Comment: @murgatroid99 Good point. I'll do that

Comment: So no Silver-Bordered Cards

Comment: Note, if your opponent helps you out, you can get significantly higher.  i.e. take David's answer, combined with Hackworth's answer as one trivial example.  So you're assuming a goldfish opponent?  If so, that seems to make Hackworth's answer less "reasonable."

Answer (score 27):

**With just 2 cards, you can be at arbitrarily many life points.**

The 2-card combo is [Black Lotus](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBlack%20Lotus%5d) and [Game of Chaos](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bGame%20of%20Chaos%5d). As long as both you and your opponent keep playing, the stakes increase indefinitely, and you can end the game whenever you win a flip.

Assuming both you and your opponent keep playing exactly until someone gets to zero life or below during Game of Chaos' resolution, you can go to 103 life with the 2 card combo, or 109 with 3 cards.

If you win (+1), lose (-2), lose (-4), win (+8), lose (-16), win (+32), win (+64), then you (and your opponent) will be at

- 21 (19),
- 19 (21),
- 15 (25),
- 23 (17),
- 7 (33),
- 39 (1),
- 103 (-63) life.

At the start of the game, reveal [Providence](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bProvidence%5d) for another 6 life - this doesn't change the sequence of coinflips because your opponent would still fall to 1 life at the same point of the sequence.

Comment: OP asks for the highest life total you can end your turn with, do you  end the turn if your opponent loses?

Comment: Of course. When the game ends, the turn ends also. You are thinking of "finishing" the turn, which is a difference.

Comment: I think the infinite-life solution is far more interesting - the goal isn't to win, it's to have the highest life total.

Comment: It would be interesting in its own way - since the game presumably still takes place in physical reality, the life total couldn't acually be infinite. You can flip a coin only so many times during the length of the game; specifically, you can flip a single coin at most once per Planck time. Assuming 1 coin at hand and a 50 minute round of a sanctioned event, you could flip it at most 5,565e+46 times, and, if you win every flip, for a life total of 19 + (2^5,565e+46) life. You couldn't use shortcut rules to name a higher number either, obviously, because coin flips.

Comment: Also, the terminology is indeed "end turn", not "finish turn" - the end step in the ending phase is commonly referred to as "end of turn", and cards that referenced "end of turn" are now errata'ed at referencing the "end step". Karn Liberated allows you to end (and restart) a game without ever reaching the end step of turn in which he was activated, so it's not really clear to me that you do actually end your turn if the game ends. It depends on how pedantic you want to be with the interpretation of the OP's "end of your turn".

Comment: [This question](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/47262/when-the-match-time-is-called-does-the-current-turn-end-immediately) was about the difference between *ending* and *finishing* a turn. Spoiler: the official tournament rules use the term "finishing" a turn to mean to take it through all its phases, while "ending" a turn means ending it immediately as per CompRules 716. Also see CR 104, "Ending the game".

Comment: There is a difference between "end the turn" as a verb, and "at the end of your first turn". Ending the turn is a specific action that is irrelevant to this question. In game cards, "at the end of your turn" is an old wording for "at the beginning of your end step".

Comment: You should use Providence instead of Radiant Fountain for 4 more

Comment: It doesn't make a whole lot of sense to assume that the person playing Game of Chaos makes their decisions in a way that rationally optimizes to achieve victory, considering that they already chose to put Game of Chaos in their deck and play it.

Answer (score 14):

Here is my best solution (**42 Life Points**):

#### 3 Cards:

- [Black Lotus](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBlack%20Lotus%5d)
- [Illusions of Grandeur](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bIllusions%20of%20Grandeur%5d)
- [Radiant Fountain](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bRadiant%20Fountain%5d)

#### Turn

1. Pass until Precombat Main Phase
2. Play Radiant Fountain [**gain 2 life**]
3. Cast Black Lotus
4. Activate Radiant Fountain
5. Activate Black Lotus's ability, adding [image] [image] [image]
6. Cast Illusions of Grandeur [**gain 20 life**]
7. Pass until End Phase

Comment: I think it is very likely that this is the greatest amount of life you can gain deterministically in a single turn with 3 cards. There aren't any good combos with just 0-cost cards, so you need mana. Illusions of Grandeur is the card that deterministically gains you the most life immediately without any other supporting cards. And Radiant Fountain is the 0-cost card that gains the most life immediately without any other supporting cards.

Comment: The best deterministic solution I can find with only two cards is 35: Nourishing Shoal + Autochthon Wurm.

Comment: You can get to 43 if you use Chancellor of the Dross, or 46 if you use Providence instead of Radiant Fountain.

Comment: @John We need the mana from Radiant Fountain to cast Illusions of Grandeur

Comment: Argh.  Very sorry to miss that point, for some reason I thought it was converted manacost 3.

Answer (score 14):

## 41 life without using Black Lotus

This is a legacy/modern entry (i.e. doesn't use [Black Lotus](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBlack%20Lotus%5d)).

Reveal [Providence](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bProvidence%5d) to go to 26 life.  Then exile [Autochthon Wurm](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAutochthon%20Wurm%5d) to cast [Nourishing Shoal](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bNourishing%20Shoal%5d) to gain 15 life.

## Multiplayer: 20 + 9 * number of opponents

The question clarifies that there are two players.  If we relax that restriction, we can do better in cases where there are 4 or more players.  Have 3 [Chancellor of the Dross](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bChancellor%20of%20the%20Dross%5d) in your opening hand and reveal all three to steal 9 life per opponent.

## 4 Cards: Arbitrarily high life

The question specifies three cards for a reason.  Allowing one more card lets you go infinite.  The 4 cards are [Black Lotus](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBlack%20Lotus%5d), [Daru Spiritualist](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDaru%20Spiritualist%5d), [Shuko](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bShuko%5d), and [Diamond Valley](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDiamond%20Valley%5d).

Use Black Lotus to Cast Daru Spiritualist and Shuko.  Repeatedly equip Shuko to Daru Spiritualist, giving Daru Spiritualist +2 toughness each time, until has [arbitrarity high odd number] toughness.  Play Diamond Valley and use it to sacrifice Daru Spiritualist to gain [arbitrarity high odd number] life.

Answer (score 6):

I'm going to cheat a bit... because you didn't specifically state that this was a 2-player game only (though you did use the word "both"...)

Hand:

- [Black Lotus](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBlack%20Lotus%5d)
- [Black Lotus](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBlack%20Lotus%5d)
- [Blood Tithe](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBlood%20Tithe%5d)

This gives you an unbounded 3n life, where n is the number of opponents you have in the game.

With only 2 cards, you can get 2n life using [Syphon Soul](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSyphon%20Soul%5d) instead.

Comment: They say "both libraries", and they also say "opponent" singular. I think this is a stretch.

Comment: I agree it's a stretch. I did mention the use of the word "both" in my answer.

Comment: 4n: [Exsanguinate](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=210235)

Comment: 3x Chancellor of the Dross for 9n

Comment: Is there any format where you can actually have two Lotuses in your deck? (EDIT: apparently "freeform" is an official format in Magic Online)

Comment: Why not just dark ritual from the lotus and not have this 2 lotus nonsense. Or I guess a swamp

Comment: I think that's not really relevant to my answer... I could have just said "4 mana and Blood Tithe". Any format casual enough to have a large number of opponents is also going to be casual enough to not follow any restricted or banned lists. "Kitchen table magic" exists; people play MTG randomly with friends without playing any specific tournament-sanctioned format.

Comment: Speaking of cheating: Since there are so many solutions with 2 lotuses despite it being restricted I'll just assume that "3 cards of your choice" means no restrictions whatsoever. Therefore you could just use 1 Blacker Lotus and you'd have a 2-card combo.

Comment: @Alex I started by looking for silver-bordered solutions before coming across this.

Comment: Just use Chancellor of the Dross and avoid this whole argument.  It's the one card equivalent of the posted combo

Comment: @Zags Ooooooh, that means we can combine the combos, i.e. Chancellor of Dross, Blacker Lotus AND Bloot Tithe. XD Now we're at 2x3n life.

Comment: @GendoIkari So you explicitly looked at Unglued etc. and then didn't remember the Blacker Lotus? That's funny. XD

Answer (score 5):

[Black Lotus](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBlack%20Lotus%5d) x 2, [Auriok Salvagers](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAuriok%20Salvagers%5d), [Stream of Life](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bStream%20of%20Life%5d)

Play the lotuses and crack them for white.  Cast Salvagers, use the 2 leftover to return lotus.

Cast lotus, crack for white, return lotus  -> repeat as much as you want to gain a white mana each loop.

Return lotus, crack for green mana, cast stream of life for x + arbitrarily large number .

Comment: I count 4 cards in your solution

Comment: @murgatroid99 He may have been solving for my 4-card infinite (although my solution was different)... Perhaps I should have been clear that that isn't what I wanted in answers.

Answer (score 4):

The best I can manage is **32 life**:

- [Black Lotus](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=382866)
- [Phyrexian Dreadnaught](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=3263)
- [Sheltering Word](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=240004)

  1. Cast Black Lotus and sacrifice for 3 green mana.
  2. Cast Phyrexian Dradnaught.
  3. In response to the etb, cast Shltering Word. [**gain 12 life**]

A second solution for **32 life**:

- [Black Lotus](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=382866)
- [Ritual of Restoration](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=48576)
- [Weather the Storm](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=464140)

  1. Cast Black Lotus and sacrifice for 3 white mana.
  2. Cast Ritual of Restoration, returning Black Lotus to hand.
  3. Cast Black Lotus and sacrifice for 3 green mana.
  4. Cast Weather the Storm, creating 3 copies with storm. [**gain 3 life * 4**]

Comment: All the other answers are accounting the initial 20 life, I suggest you do the same to provide a comparable result.

Comment: Yeah, my first assumption was that this was a joke answer and you were intentionally damaging yourself rather than gaining life.

Comment: I love that even with this combo, it's just barely above lotus+chaplain's blessing+chaplain's blessing

Answer (score 3):

[Black Lotus](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBlack%20Lotus%5d) x2
[Beacon of immortality](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBeacon%20of%20immortality%5d)

Depends on the format how much life you gain. 20 on a default game for example or 40 in Commander for example